# Laravel Guzzle returns blank response in Get() method

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I use this code to get balance from another server,
it works fine on XAMPP locally, but it doesn't on the production server, it just returns blank response page.

```
public static function balance(){
    try {
        return (string) (new \GuzzleHttp\Client())
                  ->get("http://www.*****.ps/getbalance.php?user_name=****&user_pass=*****")
                  ->getBody();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return '-';
    }
    return '-';
}
```

Comment: i guess there is a question somewhere here?

Comment: its scope of bug was diff.

Comment: what is the Http status code of the response?

Comment: @Thamer its 200

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly --- add a [mcve].

Comment: Could you try `->getBody()->getContents()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was a problem with the destination server, for some reason our server got blocked.
There is no problem in the mentioned code. It works fine.